# Как правильно реализовать систему версий для записей таблиц?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `fileState` в БД. С полями `fileId INT`, `version SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.

По крону срабатывает скрипт, который сравнивает версию файла во время последней проверки и текущую версию. Если версия поменялась, стала больше, например, то происходит его дальнейшая обработка, иначе, пропускаем этот файл.

Сейчас во время обновления файла вызывается следующий запрос:

```
UPDATE fileState SET version = IF(version = 255, 0, version+1) WHERE fileId = $fileId;
```

Однако, может возникнуть ситуация, когда крон не срабатывал и последняя его версия - 0, а файл обновлялся и после версии 255 стал 0, что при запуске приведёт к пропуску файла.

Как можно этого избежать? Какой тип данных для версий использовать менее затратно и по времени и по весу? Может `FLOAT` и хранить версии так: `0.0, ..., 0.9, 0.11, ..., 0.59`? (Пропуская десятки `9 -> 11`, `99 -> 111`)

Comment: *Какой тип данных для версий использовать менее затратно и по времени и по весу?* INTEGER. Его точно хватит до скончания века, и не надо морочиться с переполнением. А что до веса - да что у тебя тех файлов-то? уж точно не миллиард...

Comment: @Akina Так-то да, но только они редактируются в большом количестве. И через, условные полгода - год эта ситуация с версиями снова может возникнуть...

Comment: *И через, условные полгода - год эта ситуация с версиями снова может возникнуть...* Ой ли! INTEGER, даже в знаковой версии, имеет диапазон значений до 2147483647. Даже если файл обновляется ежесекундно, тебе хватит счётчика на 68 лет.